# Multiple identical values in dropdown list control

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, filter, dropdown

I am making a page which has a web part view and dropdown and search filters.
I have added datasource controls, parameters and connected these to the relevant drop down. added appenddata bound

However I am getting duplicate values in the dropdown.  There is a values for every item in the web part view. when there should be only a true and a false

I just can think what im doing wrong....:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of thinking I do not think this can be done.
The values in the dropdown are from a choice field and not a lookup.